# how to call address in flat assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

i want to use bubble sort on array but it gives me error at @data
how do i call address?
in addition, how to make a print array function ?
code:

```
 format pe; console
 entry start
include 'win32ax.inc'
 section '.code' code readable executable
start:
 mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov cx, n
dec cx
 outerloop:
  lea si, [arr]
  mov dx, cx
 innerloop:
 mov ax, [si]
 mov bx, [si+2]
 cmp ax, bx
jb next
mov [si], bx
mov [si+2], ax
next:
 add si, 02h
 dec dx
jnz innerloop
 loop outerloop
int 3h
align 16
;end
section '.data' data readable writeable
arr dd 5,8,11,7,10,4,1,9
n dd 8
 section '.idata' import data readable writeable
 library msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll', kernel32, 'kernel32.dll'
 import msvcrt, printf, 'printf', getchar,'getchar', scanf,'scanf'
 import kernel32, ExitProcess,'ExitProcess'
```

Comment: This looks confused.  The header and footer appear to be for a 32-bit Windows application, but the code itself looks like 16-bit DOS.  Where are you intending to run this?

Comment: to be honest iam confused too because iam new to this language
but i intend to use it on fasm program and i dont know the difference between the 32-bit windows app and 16-bit 
this was supposed to be a bubble sort assembly code and i wanted to test it on array

Comment: I mean, are you intending to run the program on 32-bit Windows, or 16-bit DOS, or something else?

Comment: oh, 32-bit windows

Comment: For Win32 rewrite 16bit registers to their 32bit counterparts. Do not modify `ds`. Instead of `int 3h` push zero and then `call ExitProcess`.